# How to make selenium see profile folder with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller, executable, readfile

I have some script, it has the path to the profile folder set, but when compiling with pyinstaller, it doesn't see it

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from threading import Thread
import sys
import os


def resource_path(relative_path: str) -> str:
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


class OzonBrowser:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        CHROME_PROFILE_PATH = 'profile\\'
        CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = 'driver\\chromedriver.exe'

        options = ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--allow-profiles-outfide-user-dir')
        options.add_argument('--enable-profile-shortcut-manager')
        options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={resource_path(CHROME_PROFILE_PATH)}')
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
        options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

        self.driver = Chrome(resource_path(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH), options=options)
        self.driver.get(URL)
        ...
```

i tried the following code to compile

```
pyinstaller Bot.py --onefile --noconsole --add-binary "./driver/chromedriver.exe;./driver" --add-data "./profile" --hidden-import "pynput.keyboard._win32"
```

Comment: If that's your only problem, try using ChromeDriverManager. `pip install webdriver-manager` and import it `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager` and now instead of using a path of your chromedriver it will install chromedriver or use one in cache `self.driver = Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

Comment: I have no problem with the driver, I want to use a custom path for CHROME_DRIVER_PATH

Comment: Sorry for not actually anwsering on your problem, I just suggested a workaround.